# Azure Key Vault Service to store credentials

Tags: azure, security, authentication, architecture, azure-keyvault

My Azure PaaS service supports authenticating directly with OAUTH (Event Hub).

How do you distribute the credentials for this securely to Confidential Clients?

Sorry i'm new to Cloud Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use Azure keyvault to store the [client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret) of your [Azure AD App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

Just add the client app/user account to the [Azure keyvault Access Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) with the correct permission, then only them can access your azure keyvault to retrieve the client secret.

***Update:***

You need to create a new [Azure AD App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) used to access the keyvault(this AD App is just to access keyvault, not access to eventhub), store its client id and secret as the environment variables, then use the [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets#create-secretclient) to get the secret. After that, use [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-dotnet) to access eventhub.

```
TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential("<tenantId>", "<clientId>", "<clientSecret>");

var fullyQualifiedNamespace = "<< FULLY-QUALIFIED EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE (like something.servicebus.windows.net) >>";
var eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

await using (var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, eventHubName, credential))
{
    using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync();
    eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(new BinaryData("First")));
    eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(new BinaryData("Second")));

    await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch);
}
```

Reference - [Using an Active Directory principal with the Event Hub clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Messaging.EventHubs-readme-pre#using-an-active-directory-principal-with-the-event-hub-clients)

**Note:** Actually, if your code will be deployed to the Azure service that supports [Managed Identity(MSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview), e.g. Azure App service, VM, etc, the best practice is to use MSI to auth eventhub, no need to create the AD Apps and use their client secrets, neither the keyvault.

Reference - [Authenticate a managed identity with Azure Active Directory to access Event Hubs Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authenticate-managed-identity?context=%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=latest)

Comment: Thanks Joy (Again). So the target resource is an Event Hub, what will you need to develop in the client to retrieve the vault client id/secret and apply to the code relevant to accessing a Hub?